# sending email using http protocol?

Tags: http, email, protocols

i've read on argosoft.com that it would be possible sending email using the http protocol - where can i find info about it?

i'm looking for a way to send a personalized newsletter off my server withouth putting heavy traffic on my webserver. would this be possible?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant. smtp or imap. At best you can have an http server which accepts mail and then talks smtp/imap with some mail server. Why do you think http would be less overhead?
In fact you don't have to increase the load on your webserver to send mail from your webserver domain. If the newsletter isn't too frequent you could simply have someone send it from any mail client.

If you want to automate. There's a php function too.http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
(also for java and perl)

Comment: but how does the php function work? If it doesn't use an HTTP request then what does it use?

Answer (score 3):

You can build such System. Run a Server side Script in PHP/perl/.net or anything that takes inputs like from, to, subject, body from GET/POST arguments and send the mail. and them use curl or do something similer to convey the information to that page and that page will eventually send the mails for You.

However If The SMTP server have an Web Interface then that one can also be used Similar way.